How do I formulate a type-hint for a python function that can be re-assigned in recursive calls?
Take the following minimal example:
S = TypeVar("S", bound=int | str)

def meth(a: S) -> S:
    if a == "5":
        return str(meth(int(a)))

    return a

In particular, the method above can take either a string, or an integer. It will always return a value of the same type as its input, BUT it can call itself recursively in which case the value of S may need to be re-assigned. With the typehints above, mypy gives the error:
error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "S")  [return-value]

How would I type the function above correctly?
Edit:
Thanks, it's good to know that == doesn't perform type narrowing. However, I only used that for my minimal example. A simplified version of my real-world use case looks like this:
T = TypeVar("T", bound=CSTNode)

def _rec_set_docstring(expr: T, new_str: str) -> T:
    if isinstance(expr, (BaseSuite, SimpleStatementLine)):
        return expr.with_changes(
            body=(_rec_set_docstring(expr.body[0], new_str),)
        )

    if not isinstance(expr, Expr):
        raise ValueError
    if isinstance(expr.value, (SimpleString, ConcatenatedString)):
        return expr.with_changes(value=expr.value.with_changes(value=new_str))
    raise ValueError

which yields
error: Incompatible return value type (got "BaseSuite | SimpleStatementLine", expected "T")  [return-value]

for the line of the first return and
error: Incompatible return value type (got "Expr", expected "T")  [return-value]

for the line of the second return.
This relies on libcst, but the most relevant signature should be CSTNode:
_CSTNodeSelfT = TypeVar("_CSTNodeSelfT", bound="CSTNode")
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class CSTNode(ABC):
    def with_changes(self: _CSTNodeSelfT, **changes: Any) -> _CSTNodeSelfT:
        ...


Mypy is correct here: S can be str or int (even str | int itself), or a subtype/subclass thereof. By returning just str in some cases you are essentially violating the contract. I suppose this is a contrived example and may not reflect your real code. If that is the case, please [edit] the question to provide more information.

The first issue is that a == "5" does not invoke type-narrowing, so that a is not treated by type-checkers as a str object after this equality check. I can understand why it doesn't, as arbitrary subtypes with int | str as an upper bound can override __eq__ with any behaviour. The second issue is mypy-specific, in that mypy prefers you to use a constrained type variable S = TypeVar("S", int, str) here, while Pyright doesn't care. I have no real opinion on this one.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@InSync thanks, I added a simplified version of my real use case. @dROOOze kindly pointed me to the fact that == does not perform type narrowing. Adding and isinstance(a, str) to the if statement and changing to S = TypeVar("S", int, str) indeed fixes the error for the contrived example, but I'm not quite sure how that would apply to my actual problem. When formulating my first example, I assumed the problem was that the value of S changes in recursive calls, but maybe that's not the case

I don't think the problem is the recursive call specifically, but the relationship between your function and with_changes. Basically, you don't want type narrowing in this case; you want the static type to remain T even if the arguments to with_changes will vary with the dynamic type of T. Try using cast(T, expr) instead of expr alone.

You're hitting this issue, mypy replaces typevar with upper bound for isinstance intersection type building, and upper bound is not compatible with typevar itself. Note that your first function is really unsafe: you promise to preserve any str/int subclass as well, so meth(MyStr('a')) must return MyStr instance if class MyStr(str): .... If MyStr('5') has __eq__ that makes it compare equal to '5' plain string, your code violates the contract by returning plain str. So a TypeVar('S', int, str) is the only correct way there
